# UIBarButtonItems in UINavigationBar are sticking to the borders

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm getting a weird bug since using [PageMenu](https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu) library. This library adds the ability to swipe between view controllers or change current view controller via `UISegmentedControl` (on the top).

When the view controller is a `UINavigationController`, all `UIBarButtonItems` in the navigation bar are sticking to the borders, like this :

[image]

The two items are sticking to the borders of the screen. The same thing happens with Back button after pushing to a view controller.

**The bug disappear if I present a view controller modally in the app.**

[image]

Does anybody has a solution for this ? Or at least a workaround to simulate "presenting a view controller modally" at app launch ?